# JS: How to share static class properties between imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, vite, es6-class

so I am running into this problem while I am converting some old js to new es6 imports (used in the browser).

**The problem:**
The static properties of a class are not shared between the various imports in different files.
(Even though they are bundled into one file eventually (using Vite)).

A simplified version of the code:

```js
// scripts.ts (will be three-shaked, compiled and bundled using Vite)
// This file will be loaded in a simple index.html
import Base from "./Base";
import Form from "./Form";

window.Base = Base;
window.Form = Form;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  Base.setRoot("myroot");
  
  console.log(Base.root); // 'myroot'  
  Form.logRoot(); //  'default', but expected 'myroot'
});
```

```js
// base.ts
export default class Base {
  static root: "default"

  static setRoot(root) {
    this.root = root;
  }
}
```

```js
// form.ts
import Base from "./Base"

export default class Form {
  static logRoot() {
    // attempt 1
    console.log(Base.root); // doesn't work

    // attempt 2
    console.log(window.Base.root); // works, but undesirable: TS throws error that window.Base is undefined
  }
}
```

**The question:**
So how can I share the static properties of this `Base` class between the various imports, without having to pull it from `window.Base`?

Perhaps a little background:
These classes used to be just two global `var` objects, that got bundled together, without using any imports or anything. Thus the state of the vars would be shared because they basically just lived on the `window`.

Comment: Each of the imports from `./Base` are independent versions.